# A black modal fade prevents me from typing in the text field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I've tried to create a modal that pops up when you click a link. I want the background to get faded but it seems like the whole page is getting blocked by the fade which prevents me from typing into the text field.
This is how it looks like: https://gyazo.com/d87f5beae17209d912169fde18bcdeb9

This is my code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="new-item-modal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>Submit a New Item Ticket</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="new-item-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="new-item-name">Item Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="new-item-name" placeholder="item name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="new-item-price">Item Price</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                            <input class="form-control" id="new-item-price" placeholder="item price">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="new-item-link">Item Link</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="new-item-link" placeholder="item link">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var mAllItems = [];

    $('#search').on('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            var query = this.value;

            var str = '<tr><th>Item Name</th><th>Item Price</th></tr>';

            if (query.length > 0) {
                $.getJSON('php/search-items.php', {query: query}, function (jsonObj) {
                    $('#results').html(str);
                    handleJsonResponse(jsonObj, function (data) {
                        var allItems = data['allItems'];

                        allItems.sort(function (a, b) {
                            var keyA = a['price'], keyB = b['price'];
                            return keyB - keyA;
                        });

                        mAllItems = [];

                        for (var i1 = 0; i1 < allItems.length; i1++) {
                            var item = allItems[i1];

                            var name = item['name'], price = getFormattedPrice(item['price']);

                            mAllItems.push({id: i1, name: name});

                            str += '<tr><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + price + ' <span class="item-price-change-btn" id="' + i1 + '">?</span></td></tr>';
                        }

                        $('#results').html(str);
                        $('.item-price-change-btn').on('click', itemPriceChangeHandler);
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });

    $('#new-item-form').on('submit', function () {
        var itemName = $('#new-item-name').val(),
            itemPrice = $('#new-item-price').val(),
            itemLink = $('#new-item-link').val();

        if (itemName.length === 0 || itemPrice.length === 0 || itemLink.length === 0) {
            return false;
        }

        $.post('php/new-item-ticket.php', {name: itemName, price: itemPrice, link: itemLink}, function (jsonObj) {
            handleJsonResponse(jsonObj, function (data) {
                var message = data['message'];
                successMsg(message);
                $('#new-item-modal').modal('hide');
            });
        }, 'json');

        return false;
    });

    function itemPriceChangeHandler () {
        var id = parseInt(this.id);

        var item = null;

        for (var i1 = 0; i1 < mAllItems.length; i1++) {
            var i = mAllItems[i1];
            if (i['id'] === id) {
                item = i;
            }
        }

        $('#item-price-change-modal').modal('show');
        $('#item-price-change-name').val(item['name']);
    }

    $('#item-price-change-form').on('submit', function () {
        var name = $('#item-price-change-name').val(),
            price = $('#item-price-change-price').val();

        if (name.length === 0 || price.length === 0) {
            return false;
        }

        $.post('php/item-price-change-ticket.php', {name: name, price: price}, function (jsonObj) {
            handleJsonResponse(jsonObj, function (data) {
                var message = data['message'];
                successMsg(message);
                $('#item-price-change-modal').modal('hide');
            });
        }, 'json');

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle. then it will be easy to debug your code ?

Comment: Its seems like overlay problem. I don't see your html code. can you try to remove class from your body tag or html tag using firebug when model is open ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try giving the inner element a higher z-index than the outer element.

Comment: This works and should be accepted as the right answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try applying

```
pointer-events: none;
```

To your overlay.